# ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv is full and cannot be increased anymore

Tags: server, 20.04, lvm

recently my ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv filled up so I ran

```
sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE -r /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
sudo resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
```

This worked but then shortly after it is filled up again as show in df -h

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              3.2G  1.6M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  438G  403G   16G  97% /
```

Now I cannot increase the size anymore using lvextend as it show it's out of space

```
New size (114079 extents) matches existing size (114079 extents)
```

It seems that increasing it more is not a solution but to figure out why it is getting filled up so quickly is. I cannot find any way to see how it is getting filled up so quickly and I have no idea how to decrease what's on it to free up space.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by mysql logs in /var/lib/mysql.

I fixed it by disabling logs as instructed [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-is-mysql-binary-log/)

and cleared the logs by running

```
mysql -u username -p -e "PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE '2023-10-02 10:06:06';"
```